# docker - pull image and get it's id (linux cli)

Tags: linux, docker, centos7

I am running this command in centos7 termnial:

```
 docker pull www.someRepository.com/authorization:latest
```

Now, I want to run the "docker run" command, but I need to know the **id** of the image that was created

```
$id=commandThatParsesTheId
```

Is there a command that gets the id back from the "docker images" list?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the name of image and its' tag
Or you can use

`docker images -q | grep yourimagename`

`docker images | grep yourimagename | awk {'print $3'}`

Comment: what is the image name? I don't see any name in "docker images" command

Comment: `docker run www.SomeRepository.com/authorization:latest` – the exact same name you `docker pull`ed

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to clean this up a bit, but the following should work:

```
    docker pull <someimage> | grep "Digest:" | cut -f2 -d " " > container_digest
    docker images --digests | grep $(cat container_digest) | sed -Ee 's/\s+/ /g' | cut -f4 -d " "
```

It maps the digest you receive when you pull an image to the image ID.

Answer (score 0):

you can run the "docker run" command on images name also instead of image id

```
docker pull www.someRepository.com/authorization:latest
docker run -i -t www.someRepository.com/authorization:latest "/bin/bash"
```

Above one is to run the container for interactive mode.

you can get image id also to run the docker run command

```
docker images 
docker run -i -t dockerid "/bin/bash"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
docker pull someImage:latest
docker image inspect -f '{{ .ID }}' someImage:latest
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Make sure to always explain why your code works, and/or why the original doesn't! [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)